# Why does a write and throw pen leak being overturned inside a pocket

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, pressure

I have seen many times in my life I just put my write and throw pen upsidedown into pocket rather than into my pencil box. I found the pen is leaking as my pocket used to become full of ink. I don't think this is due to gravity.I think this is due to pressure. But I can not be sure. Please help. I gave a write and throw pen's picture. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens due to the increase in temperature ,when you keep the pen in contact with the body, the heats flows from the body to the pen and the change in temperature causes the ink inside it to get warmed. The ink gets liquefied and oozes around the tip. At the other end of the tube is a small grease plug which also liquefies when warmed.The adhesive force that binds the liquid to the wall also lessens, which explains why the ink is pushed out.The tip making contact with the fabric forces ink out of the pen.In addition to the warming of the ink, the phenomena of capillary action also comes into play.